# Generate a report with multiple tables

Tags: java, reporting, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I'm completely new to jasperserver and ireport, but I've been managing. I did reach a block today and here is my problem: I'm trying to display multiple tables (maybe 50+) where each table can have the same data in the first column. The row for that column is entire different from row to row. By this I mean the following:

```
Value1 x1 y1 z1
Value1 x2 y2 z2
Value1 x3 y3 z3
Value2 x1 y1 z1
Value2 x2 y2 z2
Value2 x3 y3 z3
```

This can have the first column with similar the same value. I'm trying to change it so that each first column has its own table like so:

```
Value1 table
------------
X1   Y1   Z1
X2   Y2   Z2
X3   Y3   Z3


Value2 table
------------
X1   Y1   Z1
X2   Y2   Z2
X3   Y3   Z3
```

**Edit**

To expand on my original question, the data I'm retrieving via SQL is all stored in one table. I'm trying to break up that table with some simple formatting. I've linked a picture to hopefully ease your understanding.

[image: Multiple Table Example]
[Link to picture](https://i.imgur.com/0JwB3.png)

Is this possible in Ireport?

Comment: Rather than edit the question with an answer, post your own answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you want, but I'm going to guess...

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2;
```

`UNION ALL` differs from `UNION` in that *all* rows are returned in the order selected.
By comparison, `UNION` *sorts* all rows and discards duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on a different forum.

(In my case) make the IP a group. Then in the group header add the $Field(ID) and then the rest of the rows in the detail band. Make sure you reset on group. Good luck!